# Spatial SQL (in SSMS - using T-SQL) - STIntersect and STContains doesn't return the correct result

Tags: sql, t-sql, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

**Trying to find**:

1. All the routes that pass through a buffer of 5km around a random point.

**Background**:

1. I have multiple routes stored as linestring of type geography using the following query. The linestring is valid.

```
INSERT INTO routes (route_id, route_name, route_geography)
VALUES (
    8,
    'route-test-8',
    geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(50.47959 -80.518649, 50.47923 -80.519601, ......)', 4326)
);
```

2. I have a random point near the routes.

> **NOTE**:  For testing purposes, this random point is a point that exists in one of the routes. So in theory I should at least get 1 route in true result

3. Table structure that stores routes:

[Columns and it's types: route_geography of type geography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXrt.png)

**Tried the following query**:

1. **Used STContains**: doesn't return any route as true when in fact it should, because the (lat,long) point I select is in the route itself

```
-- Declare the "random" point

DECLARE @startPoint geography;
SET @startPoint = geography::Point('50.47959','-80.518649' , 4326); -- this is the exact point from one of the routes 

-- Create a buffer around the "random" point

DECLARE @buffer geography;
SET @buffer = @startPoint.STBuffer(5000); -- Create a 5km radius buffer

-- Finding the routes that pass through the buffer

SELECT [route_id], [route_name],[route_geography].
FROM [test-DB].[dbo].[routes]
WHERE @buffer.STContains([route_geography]) = 1; -- when assigned 0 returns all the routes
```

2. **Used STIntersect**: same result as with STContains

```
-- Declare the "random" point

DECLARE @startPoint geography;
SET @startPoint = geography::Point('50.47959','-80.518649' , 4326); -- this is the exact point from one of the routes 

-- Create a buffer around the "random" point

DECLARE @buffer geography;
SET @buffer = @startPoint.STBuffer(5000); -- Create a 5km radius buffer

-- Finding the routes that pass through the buffer

SELECT [route_id], [route_name]
FROM [test-DB].[dbo].[routes]
WHERE [route_geography].STIntersects(@buffer) = 1; -- when assigned 0 returns all the routes
```

Comment: SSMS is just a GUI interface. You need to tell us (tag) what database engineer you are using. Telling us you are using SSMS is like telling us the programming language you are using is Visual Studio.

Comment: My bad, it is T-SQL

Comment: T-SQL is the dialect, but that's still used by several products. Are you using SQL Server? Sybase? Synapse? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the arguments you are giving to `geography::Point` are in the wrong order. The function `geography::Point` takes first Lat, then Long. This is different from WKT where coordinates are given as first Long then Lat. This is helpfully pointed out in a note in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16